# add text from textbox to listview column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` with 3 columns. When I click a button, I want the first text to go to the first column, second text to the second column, and third text to the third column, but it's not working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Column[0].SubItems.Add("my first text")
    listView1.Column[1].SubItems.Add("my second text")
    listView1.Column[2].SubItems.Add("my third text")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please post it up and show us where you are stuck

Comment: Is this WPF? If it is, please add the relevant XAML (or code generating the button) and tag this question as WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Items** first before **subitems** so try:

```
       listView1.View = View.Details;

       ListViewItem lvwItem = listView1.Items.Add("my first text");
       lvwItem.SubItems.Add("my second text");
       lvwItem.SubItems.Add("my third text");
```

Comment: @macstac Make sure your View property is View.Details. Anyway I changed my code to do that programmatically.

Comment: I can view the column headers. I just cant add any item under column

Comment: have you made an edit ? It seems you edited something. now it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: @macstac I tried it on my PC and it works. I have added three columns by the way before running the program since you have three columns implied in your example.

Comment: @macstac I changed the View to View.Details as I've said on one of my comment above. Glad it works for you. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Comment: @macstac .. you should vote this as the answer .. make green check below the downvote sign ..