# Add text from a Textbox to a ListView column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ListView with 2 columns. When I click a  **ADD** button, I want the first text to go to the first column, second text to the second column, but it's not working.

I am using Visual studio 2003, c# WPF.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
ListViewItem lvwItem = listView1.Items.Add("TextBox1.Text");
lvwItem.SubItems.Add("TextBox2.Text");
```

Comment: Hello. And welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with the example of what you've tried to do.

Comment: Hello! Does your question answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225675/add-text-from-textbox-to-listview-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add text from textbox to listview column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225675/add-text-from-textbox-to-listview-column)

Comment: I tried that code, but it's also not working.. View.Details and SubItems  Property is not there.

Comment: Your provided code used windows form method, When your prj is WPF, thats why it doesnt work!

Comment: give me any code to add item to listview column